# 'CPythonGraphic::SaveJPEG': cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'LPBYTE'

Tags: c++

my english is not realy the best but i hope you will understand my 
problem im actually using vs2010 to compiling a project and getting a
error and because im new in C++ i cannot solve this error but maybe 
you can help me out to solve this error ! :)

```
 error C2664: 'CPythonGraphic::SaveJPEG' : cannot convert parameter 2
 from 'char *' to 'LPBYTE'
```

source part:

```
 bool CPythonGraphic::SaveJPEG(const char * pszFileName, LPBYTE
 pbyBuffer, UINT uWidth, UINT uHeight) {    return jpeg_save(pbyBuffer,
 uWidth, uHeight, 85, pszFileName) != 0; }
```

Comment: Did you declare pbyBuffer as char*? Look how LPBYTE is defined on your platform, e.g. unsigned char*

Comment: omg thank you ! solved but i do not have the privilege to vote up your solution because im new here .. hope its okay but your answer solve my problem thanks dude !